# Eclipse. Как его полностью отвязать от системного JAVA_HOME и JAVA_JRE?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

У меня системный JAVA_HOME восьмая версия. Сейчас нужно запустить проект, который будет работать на семерке.

`eclipse.ini`

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
384M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
384m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms384m
-Xmx2048m
```

В самом Eclipse в настройках компилятор 1.7, **jdk = C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_80** и сервер tomcat на семерке. Проект не запускается

> "Exception in thread "main" Exception in thread
> "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager"

Это потому, что каким-то образом все равно запускается с 8 джавой.

Вот часть информации:

`Help->About Eclipse->Installation Details->Configuration`

```
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
-vm
C:\Java\jre1.8.0_202\bin\server\jvm.dll
eclipse.home.location=file:/Z:/................................./eclipse/
eclipse.launcher=Z:\...................................\eclipse\eclipse.exe
eclipse.launcher.name=Eclipse
eclipse.p2.data.area=@config.dir/../p2/
eclipse.p2.profile=epp.package.jee
eclipse.product=org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
eclipse.startTime=1617183455259
eclipse.stateSaveDelayInterval=30000
eclipse.vm=C:\Java\jre1.8.0_202\bin\server\jvm.dll
eclipse.vmargs=-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms384m
-Xmx2048m
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms384m
-Xmx2048m
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms384m
-Xmx2048m
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms384m
-Xmx1024m
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms384m
-Xmx1024m
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms384m
-Xmx1024m
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms384m
-Xmx1024m
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms384m
-Xmx1024m
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms384m
-Xmx1024m
-Djava.class.path=Z:\.......................\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
equinox.use.ds=true
file.encoding=Cp1251
file.encoding.pkg=sun.io
file.separator=\
```

Можно ли запустить Eclipse используя только 7 джаву, игнорируя 8 по умолчанию?

Comment: Точно такая же ошибка, если проект запускаю на прямую без эклипса. Но когда добавляю в bat файл ```set "JAVA_HOME=C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_80"
 set "JRE_HOME=%JAVA_HOME%"``` , проект запускается на ура.

Comment: JRE на котором запускаете проект не связан никак с JRE, который использует сам еклипс. Какой JRE указан в `Run Configuration`, который используете для запуска проекта?

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в eclipse в `Preferences -> Java -> Installed Environments -> Add..` JRE, который вам нужен.

Потом его используйте в проекте по умолчанию (`Свойства проекта -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> JRE System Library -> Edit -> Execution Environment)` или задавайте вручную для каждой `Run Configuration`.